# PIL python package removes tensorflow from environment

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, python-imaging-library, conda

I am using Tensorflow-gpu in a virtual environment running Python 3.6.8 and Tensorflow 1.13.

I am  trying to install PIL using below :
conda install -c anaconda pil

However, this removes tensorflow and keras installation and even corrupts the proxy settings as well. Below is the list of packages that it is trying to remove:

1. grpcio-1.16.1-py37h351948d_1   keras-2.2.4-0
   keras-base-2.2.4-py37_0   mkl_random-1.0.2-py37h343c172_0
   tensorboard-1.13.1-py37h33f27b4_0
   tensorflow-1.13.1-gpu_py37h83e5d6a_0
   tensorflow-base-1.13.1-gpu_py37h871c8ca_0
   tensorflow-gpu-1.13.1-h0d30ee6_0

Comment: Could you copy the text of your image in the question?

Comment: @Hoog, I have just added the text as you requsted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PIL doesn't support Python 3, which is probably why it's trying to remove all of the libraries you have installed.

Use [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.0/installation.html) instead, which is the actively maintained fork of the original PIL library that does support it.

`conda install -c anaconda pillow`

Comment: Thanks. It worked :) However, I found that , even after installing pillow, both (import PIL) and (import pillow) resulted in ModuleNotFound error but the following worked :                 
from PIL import image

Could you help explain why ?

Comment: Pillow is a fork of PIL so even though the install name is `pillow`, the correct import is `PIL`.  `import PIL` should still work - it does for me.